# can a .local domain be added to windows azure?

Tags: windows, azure, local, domains

can a .local domain be added to windows azure ?

I have a test deployment of 3 servers on azure running windows server 2012 R2 1 of them is a domain controller, I wish to added the other 2 servers to a .local domain as it is only a test environment and do not wish to use a .com domain, can a .local domain be used within an Windows Azure environment ? if so does anyone know how to set this up ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name an Active Directory domain as you wish, it doesn't matter if the domain is hosted on phyical servers, local VMs or Azure VMs; just treat it as any other AD domain. For a test deployment, a .local suffix is fine (but really, any suffix would do).

Azure doesn't care at all if your virtual servers are domain controllers or domain members, or what their AD domain name is. Just make sure they are connected to the same virtual network (create one if you didn't already) and the virtual network is configured to use your DC as a DNS server.

Comment: Do you have anymore info on this please I've added two servers that I want to start with the domain into a private subnet, the DC creates a domain but my other server cannot connect to the DC's domain.

Comment: First of all, you need to create a virtual network and connect your servers to it; if you haven't done this, then you will need to re-deploy your servers, because you can't connect an Azure VM to a virtual network after it has been deployed without one.